# OPTIONS request failing to api.finder.healthcare.gov from the browser?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

Is anyone successfully making requests to the healthcare api from the browser? I can do it successfully from the command line, or from the Postman REST client (which has special Chrome permissions). But if I try to do it from the browser using just $.ajax, it gives me a 501 on the preflight OPTIONS request.

I couldn't see anything in the [documentation](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services/version_3_0) about an OPTIONS request. Anyone else run into this?